# How to access $rootScope variable from directive templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've managed to get cross-domain HTML templates working by applying a url to the rootScope which I can access from controllers and other HTML files, but the problem arises when it comes to accessing the template from a directive. Here's my directive code:

```
angular.module("bertha")
    .directive("bthToggleHeader", function() {
    var controller = [
        "$scope", "$rootScope", "_", function ($scope, $rootScope, _) {
            if ($scope.tglOpen)
                $scope.tglShowSection = true;

            $scope.toggleShowSection = function() {
                $scope.tglShowSection = !$scope.tglShowSection;
            };
        }
    ];

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            tglHeading: "@",
            tglShowSection: "=",
            tglOpen: "=?"
        },
        transclude: true,
        controller: controller,
        templateUrl: $rootScope.cdnUrl +  "/html/directives/bthToggleHeader.html"
    };
});
```

When attempting this I get: `ReferenceError: $rootScope is not defined`. Is there something blatantly obvious that I'm doing wrong here?

In a work project we tried using the link function but that didn't play nicely with being minified at all, hence the controller approach.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use angular's dependency injection at directive level - so just place `$rootScope` there. See my example below:

```
angular
  .module('bertha')
  .directive('bthToggleHeader', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    var controller = [
      '$scope', '_',
      function($scope, _) {
        if ($scope.tglOpen)
          $scope.tglShowSection = true;

        $scope.toggleShowSection = function() {
          $scope.tglShowSection = !$scope.tglShowSection;
        };
      }
    ];

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        tglHeading: '@',
        tglShowSection: '=',
        tglOpen: '=?'
      },
      transclude: true,
      controller: controller,
      templateUrl: $rootScope.cdnUrl + '/html/directives/bthToggleHeader.html'
    };
  }]);
```

As Joe Clay said, `$rootScope` exists only in the controller function - that's why it's undefined outside of it.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you! I'll give that a go when I'm next working on the project and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

`$rootScope` has fallen out of scope by the time you try to access it in `templateUrl` - you can't use a function parameter outside of the function (or at least, not without saving a reference somewhere)!

```
var controller = [
    "$scope", "$rootScope", "_", function ($scope, $rootScope, _) {
        if ($scope.tglOpen)
            $scope.tglShowSection = true;

        $scope.toggleShowSection = function() {
            $scope.tglShowSection = !$scope.tglShowSection;
        };
    } // FUNCTION ENDS HERE - past this point $rootScope is undefined!
];
```

**EDIT:** While this answer gives some context on *why* your current code doesn't work, I wasn't 100% sure of the best way to solve the problem - Cosmin Ababei's answer seems like an effective solution, and I'd recommend you follow his advice!