# Get $rootScope in a directive's templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is it possible to get the `$rootScope` object in a directive's templateUrl?
I mean, if this is my directive's function:

```
function AttributesCard() {

        return {
            restrict: "AE",
            templateUrl: function ($rootScope) {
                return $rootScope.baseUrl +  "/attributesCard.directive.html";
            },
            controller: AttributesCardController,
            controllerAs: "vm",
            scope: {
                educationPlace: "=",
                privileges: "="
            },
            bindToController: true
        };
    }
```

how do I get the $rootScope object inside the templateUrl's function? I get someting else inside of it. Or perhaps instead of the $rootScope a service that might get this data for me.

Thanks,
ashilon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access $rootScope variable from directive templateUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36007277/how-to-access-rootscope-variable-from-directive-templateurl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can inject anything in your directive just as in your controllers, services etc:

```
app.directive("name", ["$rootScope", "myService", function($rootScope, myService) {
    // ..
    templateUrl: function () {
        var baseUrl = $rootScope.baseUrl; // or myService.baseUrl;
        return baseUrl +  "/attributesCard.directive.html";
    },
    // ..
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks devqon. your answer helped me a lot. I just made a little change: Instead of injecting the $rootScope object in the anonnymous function like you showed, I injected it in the function AttributesCard, like this: function AttributesCard($rootScope) { ... }